# goDaddy SMTP-Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am trying to set up mail functionality using goDaddy smtp servers,Go daddy support is also not very useful here.

I have tried these servers:

*relay-hosting.secureserver.net* -Errors-Unable to connect\

*smtpout.secureserver.net* -Errors-Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed

This is what goDaddy says:

[image]

This is my code snippet:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("signup@xxx-xxx.com", to);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtpout.asia.secureserver.net";
//Tried "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" -Errors-Unable to connect
//Tried "smtpout.secureserver.net" -Errors-Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed
client.Port = 25;
//Tried 80, 3535, 25, 465 (SSL)
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1;
client.Timeout = 1000;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("signup@xxx-xxx.com", "xxx-xxx");
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Subject = "xxx-xxx.com Account Activation";

mail.Body = SomeBigHTMLstring;
client.Send(mail);
mail.Dispose();
```

and this is the error page am getting

[image]
[image]

Help me out guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.Two things to note

1. The emails configured with "Relays" are only working this way as depicted below.
   [image]
2. The Timeout needs to be increased.

```cs
client.Timeout = 10000;//was 1000 initialy
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use port no : 3535 and EnableSSl:false after that is problem is resolved...

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("signup@xxx-xxx.com", to);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtpout.asia.secureserver.net";

// Tried "relay-hosting.secureserver.net" -Errors-Unable to connect
// Tried "smtpout.secureserver.net" -Errors-Unable to read data from
// the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed

client.Port = 3535;  //Tried 80, 3535, 25, 465 (SSL)
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1;
client.Timeout = 1000;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("signup@xxx-xxx.com", "xxx-xxx");
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Subject = "xxx-xxx.com Account Activation";
mail.Body = SomeBigHTMLstring;
client.Send(mail);
mail.Dispose();
```

Happy coding... :-)

Comment: this worked for me in Europe - smtpout.europe.secureserver.net doesnt say anywhere in the documentation about port - 3535?

Comment: +1, you just need to increase Timout : 
**client.Timeout = 10000;**